# Fivem lua config

Tags: lua, fivem

I am pretty new in lua and wanted to create a client sided script that draws a marker on specific coordinates. unfortunately, when i reload the resource it says

> attempt to index a nil value (global 'Config')
> This is my config file:

```
Config = {}

Config.MarkerType=1
```

And this is the method I am trying to work with:

```
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(1)
        DrawMarker(Config.MarkerType, 400.3, -1157.4, 28.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 255, 0, 0, 170, false, true, 2, nil, nil," ", false)
    end
end)
```

Can anyone help me?
I have 2 folders in my resource folder named "client" and "server". Both contain a file named "main.lua". __resource.lua contains:

```
shared_script 'client/config.lua'
server_scripts {
    'server/main.lua'
}

client_scripts {
    'client/main.lua'
}
```

I have ESX=nil at the begining of my client sided script, so I don't really understand the problem here.

Comment: has your config file been executed at some point? the error indicates that it has not.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the scripts attempts to index something that hasn't been defined (`Config.MarkerType`), it could be meaning multiple things :

- The file containing the `Config` array wasn't loaded
- There is an error in the file containing the `Config` array definition
- The file containing the `Config` array is loaded after the client file

It doesn't seem to be the last two, therefore :

> I have 2 folders in my resource folder named "client" and "server". Both contain a file named "main.lua". __resource.lua contains:

Where is your `config.lua` located ?

If it's next to `__resource.lua` then you should edit your file like so

```lua
shared_script 'config.lua'
server_scripts {
    'server/main.lua'
}

client_scripts {
    'client/main.lua'
}
```